# Два потока с очередями Python 3, подскажите код

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, очередь

*Вообще не понимаю потоков, поэтому прошу подсобить кодом или примером, пожалуйста.*

Нужны два потока: один принимает сообщения, засовывает их в луп (как в библиотеке Queue, с помощью её, думаю, и нужно), а другой поток работает одновременно и обрабатывает те запросы, что находятся в лупе.

Answer (score 2):

Информации же полно в сети, например, на Хабре:
[Учимся писать многопоточные и многопроцессные приложения на Python](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/)

В качестве примера на основе статьи:

```
import time
import multiprocessing


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, sender, send_msg, receive_msg):
        super().__init__()
        self.sender = sender
        self.send_msg = send_msg
        self.receive_msg = receive_msg

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.sender:
                try:
                    msg = self.send_msg.get()
                    print('sent message:', msg)
                    self.receive_msg.put(msg)
                    time.sleep(2)
                finally:
                    self.send_msg.task_done()
            else:
                try:
                    msg = self.receive_msg.get()
                    print('received message:', msg)
                    time.sleep(1)
                finally:
                    self.receive_msg.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_msg = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    receive_msg = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

    sender = Worker(True, send_msg, receive_msg)
    sender.daemon = True
    sender.start()

    recipient = Worker(False, send_msg, receive_msg)
    recipient.daemon = True
    recipient.start()

    messages = ('Hello, World!', 'How are you?', 'Nice to meet you!', 'By, by!')
    for msg in messages:
        send_msg.put(msg)

    send_msg.join()
    receive_msg.join()
```

Comment: Этот код должен обрабатывать сообщения из списка messages, верно? Но он не выводит их.

Comment: Да, он ничего не выводит и даже не использует run(), как оказалось. Вместо sender.start() и recepient.start() поставила sender.run() и recepient.run(), но он все равно не принимает сообщения и также не выводит их.

Comment: @Julia, вы получаете какую-то ошибку или просто отсутствует вывод и программа завершается? На версии 3.6.1 пример работает. И для того, чтобы метод `run` запускался именно в отдельном процессе, надо все же вызывать `start`. [multiprocessing.Process.start](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.start)

Comment: @mkkik Версия 3.6.0.Сейчас затестила так: при использовании run() выводится единичка. Код завершается (чего, кстати, не должно быть), единичка не выводится. А еще сообщения из messages совсем не обрабатываются.

Comment: @Julia, попробуйте дебаггером пройти пошагово, чтобы понять, в чем проблема.

Comment: @mkkik попробовала поставить цикл с отправкой сообщений из messages после объявления send_msg и receive_msg, заработало. Значит, сообщения просто не попадают в run().

Answer (score 2):

```
import threading, queue, time, random, contextlib

class ThreadWorker(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):  # worker-поток
        with contextlib.suppress(queue.Empty):
            while True:
                task = queue_in.get(timeout=10)  # получить
                print(f'queue_in: {self.name} {task}')
                task['result'] = task['func'](*task.get('args', ()), **task.get('kwargs', {}))  # выполнить
                queue_out.put(task)  # сохранить результат
                queue_in.task_done()

def run_in_thread(func):  # создать и добавить task в queue_in
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        task = dict(func=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        queue_in.put(task)
    return wrap

def my_func(message, slp=1):  # какая-то функция
    time.sleep(slp)
    return f' Done {message}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue_in, queue_out = queue.Queue(), queue.Queue()
    for _ in range(4):  # создать(пул) 4 потока + стартовать run()
        ThreadWorker().start()

    for n in range(3):  # выполнить my_func в пуле(3x2=6 раз)
        m, s = f'MSG_{n}', random.randrange(5)
        run_in_thread(my_func)(m, slp=s)  # с помощью run_in_thread
        queue_in.put(dict(func=my_func, args=[m], kwargs={'slp': s}))  # или так

    with contextlib.suppress(queue.Empty):
        while True:  # посмотреть очередь результатов
            task = queue_out.get(timeout=10)
            print(f'queue_out: {threading.current_thread().getName()} {task}')
            queue_out.task_done()
```

out:

```
queue_in: Thread-1 {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ('MSG_0',), 'kwargs': {'slp': 1}}
queue_in: Thread-2 {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ['MSG_0'], 'kwargs': {'slp': 1}}
queue_in: Thread-4 {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ('MSG_1',), 'kwargs': {'slp': 0}}
queue_in: Thread-3 {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ['MSG_1'], 'kwargs': {'slp': 0}}
queue_in: Thread-4 {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ('MSG_2',), 'kwargs': {'slp': 2}}
queue_out: MainThread {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ('MSG_1',), 'kwargs': {'slp': 0}, 'result': ' Done MSG_1'}
queue_in: Thread-3 {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ['MSG_2'], 'kwargs': {'slp': 2}}
queue_out: MainThread {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ['MSG_1'], 'kwargs': {'slp': 0}, 'result': ' Done MSG_1'}
queue_out: MainThread {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ['MSG_0'], 'kwargs': {'slp': 1}, 'result': ' Done MSG_0'}
queue_out: MainThread {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ('MSG_0',), 'kwargs': {'slp': 1}, 'result': ' Done MSG_0'}
queue_out: MainThread {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ('MSG_2',), 'kwargs': {'slp': 2}, 'result': ' Done MSG_2'}
queue_out: MainThread {'func': <function my_func at 0x03A63B28>, 'args': ['MSG_2'], 'kwargs': {'slp': 2}, 'result': ' Done MSG_2'}
```

но есть стандартные пулы, например тоже самое с использованием ThreadPool

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def my_func(message, slp=1):  # какая-то функция
    print(f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} {message} {slp}')
    time.sleep(slp)
    return f'Done {message} {slp}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(my_func, args=[f'MSG_{n}'], kwds=dict(slp=random.randrange(5))) for n in range(6)]
        for r in results:
            print(r.get())  # результат выполнения
```

Comment: Можете объяснить последний вариант, пожалуйста?